# Open Source Canvas - NoMethodError (undefined method `lti_guid'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, canvas

I'm trying to install 'Open Source Canvas' from the following documentation (https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start).

I have it installed, but after starting the server and trying to hit the URL I get a "NoMethodError (undefined method `lti_guid'" error.

/var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.6.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:432:in `method_missing':

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  if respond_to_without_attributes?(method, true)
    super
  else
    match = matched_attribute_method(method.to_s)
    match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
  end
end
```

I have zero experience in Ruby so this is a bit tricky.

**Using:**

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Rails: 5.1.6.2

Gem: 2.6.14.4

Ruby: 2.4.6p354 (2019-04-01 revision 67394) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Yarn: 1.10.1

PostregreSQL: 10.9

NPM: 6.9.0

Comment: Did you run migration successfully?